# Kernel Question

Tags: grub2, kernel, oracle, oem

I've had this happen before and just ignored it in the past. I can no longer ignore it because Grub Customizer is not available through the repos now.

Why do I keep getting kernel images that are not for my system? Before, I would just not allow them to install during an update; this time, I was busy. Now I have four brand-new entries which will not work.

I have added some of the 32-bit repos for wine configurations that I'm using for some older games I have.

I ran this command so I could figure out why this keeps happening from time to time over the years:

```bash
sudo dpkg --list | egrep 'linux-image|linux-headers'
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-52     5.15.0-52.58   all Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-52-generic                   5.15.0-52.58                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                             5.15.0.52.52                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1021-oracle                    5.15.0-1021.27                              amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic                     5.15.0-43.46                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic                     5.15.0-47.51                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic                     5.15.0-48.54                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic                     5.15.0-50.56                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic                     5.15.0-52.58                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.17.0-1020-oem                       5.17.0-1020.21                              amd64        Signed kernel image OEM
ii  linux-image-generic                               5.15.0.52.52                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

As you can see, I have OEM and Oracle kernel entries in my grub boot loader conf file now.

I can get ride of them myself, but why do I get these images which are for either servers or IoT devices (I assume) and how, if they show back up and I get busy again and have to walk away from another update, do I keep them from installing?

Oh, by the way, these installed through discover, not the terminal. The only reason I'm asking this because it's kind of getting irritating.

Comment: The entries starting with "rc" have been removed, but not purged, leaving some "config" files around.  Use sudo apt-get purge xxxx to eliminate those. You must have installed the 5.17 kernel at some point, if it is not the running kernel, you may purge it too.

Comment: Find the packages that depend on them: `apt-cache rdepends linux-image-5.16.0.1020-oem`. If nothing turns up, you can safely delete them.

Comment: Do you have a Dell computer that came with Ubuntu preinstalled? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I run `sudo apt remove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}')` when I have these "removed but not purged" situations/

Answer (score 0):

This might come across as flippant at first. It's not meant that way. It's 100% sincere.

Your questions are "why does it happen?" and "how can I prevent it from happening?" Any firefighter can tell you the answers:

1. You initiated an action that could do a lot of damage and then you walked away from it;
2. Don't do that.

**[Murphy is always in charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law).**